# ng-click does not trigger the function associated with it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-include

I am having troubles with using ng-click. I have added ng-click directive to the button. It does not trigger the function associated with ng-click. In Angular Batarang tool, it says the functions are undefined.

I tried the problem in Plunker.It does work. And also If i hard code the file path it works.

index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<HTML ng-app="myEventApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldController">{{ helloMessage }}</h1>
            <div ng-controller="EventDetail">
            </div>
            <div ng-include="" src="fileName"></div>
            <!--<ng-include src="fileName"></ng-include>-->
            <!--<div ng-include="" src="'template/testing10000.html'"></div>-->
            <button ng-click=incrementCounter()>Next</button>
            <button ng-click=decrementCounter()>Back</button>
            <script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"> </script>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

app.js code

```
var app = angular.module("myEventApp", []);

app.controller('HelloWorldController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.helloMessage = "Book Viewer";
}]);


app.controller('EventDetail', ['$scope', function($scope){

        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.fileName = 'template/testing1000'+$scope.counter+'.html';


        $scope.incrementCounter = function(){
              $scope.counter++;
              $scope.fileName = 'template/testing1000'+$scope.counter+'.html';
              console.log($scope.counter);
        }

        $scope.decrementCounter = function(){
              $scope.counter--;
              $scope.fileName = 'template/testing1000'+$scope.counter+'.html';
              console.log($scope.counter);
        }


}]);
```

Comment: Didn't go into detail but hard coding file paths sounds like you need a `<base>`-Tag

Comment: Seems a typo to me as `div` is closed and `ng-click` expression is used which is out of the context..https://jsfiddle.net/t5qs0ta4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declared the functions inside the `EventDetail` controller, but you have the buttons outside of the controller container in the html.

```
<div ng-controller="EventDetail">
    <div ng-include="" src="fileName"></div>

    <button ng-click="incrementCounter()">Next</button>
    <button ng-click="decrementCounter()">Back</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: Great. It is working like a charm now. I wish you a great day.